# Change IntelliJ IDEA select item background color in search result dialog

Tags: intellij-idea

Where can I change the selected line background from blue bar to transparent in the pop dialog, so that not hide the original font colors?

such as:
word 'import' in the select text is purple not white

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.

[image]
￼

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General and then in Search Results sections you can edit the colors as you like:

[image]

Comment: Can I modify the blue background color on the selected text "General" and the selected  text "Search result"  in the dialog  to transparent? not the text in the edit.@Mate Mrše